# Python MemoryError trying to split large string

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x

I'm getting a memory error when trying to split a very big string.

```
data = load_data(file_name) # loads data string from file
splited_data = data.split('\n\n')
```

why is it and how it can be fixed? 
working with python 2.7

Comment: Do you need the complete list of parts, or are you processing them one at a time?

Comment: I am using for loop to process them one by one @s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `load_data` is reading the entire file into memory and it is clear you don't have enough memory to do that. So you will have to abandon the idea of having a read phase followed by a processing phase. Instead, read your file a line at a time, and process the lines as you get them.

This will split your file into strings in the same way as `data.split('\n\n')` but one line at a time:

```
with open("mybigfile.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        mydata = line.rstrip()
        if mydata:
            do_something_with(mydata)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are processing the parts of the string one by one you can use a generator to emit each part separately; this will reduce the amount of memory used because you won't generate a list of all the parts, as you do with `str.split`.

```
>>> s = 'abc\n\ndef\n\nghi'

>>> def splitter(s):
...     chars = []
...     for x in s:
...         chars.append(x)
...         # Check for split characters and yield string
...         if chars[-2:] == ['\n', '\n']:
...             yield ''.join(chars[:-2])
...             chars = []
...     yield ''.join(chars)
... 
>>> 
>>> for word in splitter(s):
...     print word
... 
abc
def
ghi
```

Comment: now I'm getting the error on the chars.append(x) line

Comment: That suggests that your program is already using most of the available memory, and at least some of the parts of the string are so long that they are consuming all the remaining memory.  Not sure what you can do apart from get more memory, or find a way to load that string into your program incrementally.